# Can PDFbox PDFRenderer respect Overprint?

Tags: pdfbox, renderer

We are trying to use PDFBox to render previews of PDF Files.  We've run into some of the files that have EXTGstate with OV=1 and/or OPM=1 which turn on Overprinting.

PDFBox rendering doesn't seem to respect those, so the preview ends up just showing the last color that was drawn.

Is there any way to have it respect the Overprint settings?

Comment: No it's not supported, and there is no work on it.

Comment: Ouch.  Now we have to decided if this is a showstopper.